# Why does Google PageSpeed Insights doesn't show the Core Web Vitals for all websites?

Tags: pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

For this website (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l56Wf.png) pagspeed insights is showing the Core Web Vitals option.

But for this website (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTNOO.png) pagspeed insights is not showing the Core Web Vitals option.

I want to know Why?

I am searching for the answer on the internet but I didn't find a satisfactory answer yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Web Vitals data in PageSpeed Insights is powered by the [Chrome UX Report](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/methodology/) dataset. The linked documentation talks about the eligibility criteria for a single page or whole website to be included, in particular that it needs to be sufficiently popular and publicly discoverable.